# Three.js / web VR.: alpha renders black. how to set it to transparent?

Tags: three.js, webvr

I am using [WebVR starter kit](https://github.com/povdocs/webvr-starter-kit) (The simplified API is a wrapper for three.js) to simulate a VR tour. The problem is that the Renderer renders alpha black:

[VR simulation](https://jsbin.com/hugubez)

I believe the Renderers is VR.renderer, and I try use renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ) to set the black color to transparent. it didn't work. Now I have no clue and completely stuck.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="//povdocs.github.io/webvr-starter-kit/build/vr.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var renderer = VR.renderer;
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );

var mark1 = VR.image('http://i.imgur.com/6Pae8y7.png').setScale(0.2);

mark1.text({text:"Focus"}).moveTo(0,0.8,0);

var focus = VR.camera.torus({radius:0.02,
           tube:0.01,
           color:"white",
           }).moveTo(0,0,-4);

var img1 = "http://i.imgur.com/7Wc2FZh.jpg";
var img2 = "http://i.imgur.com/hkf4fvk.jpg"
var img3 = "http://i.imgur.com/4nMNbYY.png";
var imgs = [img1, img2, img3];
var i = 0;

VR.panorama(imgs[i]);

VR.on('lookat', function(target){
    if (target === mark1.object)
        VR.vibrate(250);
        i=(i+1)%3;
        VR.panorama(imgs[i]);
    });
```

You may play with the code in [here](https://jsbin.com/hugubez/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 3):

From what I see mark1.text() returns a THREE.Object3D. You need to set the following material properties (after its call):

```
mark1.material.transparent=true;
mark1.material.alphaTest=0.5;
```

Make sure to change the `alphaTest` value to suit your needs.